# SetErrorHandler in not supproted in Kafka 3.1.1 version and deprecated in 3.0.14 what is the replacement

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In Spring boot 3.1.2, this method is deprecated. This is the `KafkaConfig` class:

```java
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new 
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    //        deprecated
    factory.setErrorHandler((exception, data) -> {
        log.error("exception occurred while processing data {} and the data is {}",
            exception, data);
    });
    return factory;
}
```

What is the replacement sample for this? The doc says, I should use `setCommonErrorHandler`, but how to implement the `CommonErrorHandler` interface, as no method to be overriden is there?

This is not blocking, just an annoying deprecated message though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in the Javadocs of that deprecated method:

```
/**
 * Set the error handler to call when the listener throws an exception.
 * @param errorHandler the error handler.
 * @since 2.2
 * @deprecated in favor of {@link #setCommonErrorHandler(CommonErrorHandler)}
 * @see #setCommonErrorHandler(CommonErrorHandler)
 */
@Deprecated(since = "2.8", forRemoval = true) // in 3.1
public void setErrorHandler(org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
```

Also see docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html